# Should I be mentioning things on my cover letter already addressed in my CV?

Tags: resume, cover-letter

I'm trying to draft up a cover letter template for the job search, but much of it is essentially repeating qualifications and internships I've already mentioned in my CV. Should I be mentioning these things, or just getting to why I think I would be a good fit?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I be mentioning these things

Yes, absolutely.

Your resume describes you: your skills, experiences and achievements. That's "one-size-fits" all and is the same for all application.

The cover letter is unique to each application. It

1. explains why are you good fit for the job and why is the job a good fit for you
2. Demonstrates that you have done homework on the specific position and company
3. Assess how you stack up against the requirements: what does the job need and which items in your resume demonstrates that you meet these needs. That's where you re-iterate stuff from your resume using the requirements as a guideline and structure.

So in short. Your resume is the same for all applications, the job description is the same for all candidates and your cover letter is the thing that ties the two together and makes it specific to you and this role.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things on your resume are more relevant than others. Typically you have the same resume for several different jobs, but a different cover letter for each. So in one letter you might call out a degree you hold, knowing that the job ad mentioned that degree was required. In another, you might not mention the degree, but might have several sentences about a project you worked on recently that's directly applicable to their business.

All the things you mention in your cover letter are also on your CV, but you're extracting just a few and highlighting them, rather than hoping the screener will notice them mixed in with the slightly less relevant things. For this reason, you really can't pre-write a template. A cover letter that's the same for every job is pointless. Write each one for each job and explain what a lovely fit you happen to be for it.

Answer (score 0):

The resume/CV should be tailored for each job you are applying for. Sometimes an application requires you to list every job you ever had, but the CV/resume is a document you write to highlight your experiences, skills, and achievements. You are tying to  list either general experience or specific experience that would apply to the job you are seeking.

> I'm trying to draft up a cover letter template for the job search, but
> much of it is essentially repeating qualifications and internships
> I've already mentioned in my CV. Should I be mentioning these things,
> or just getting to why I think I would be a good fit?

The cover letter is a way to highlight information in the resume to make sure they see the items you feel are either your strengths or extremely relevant for this position; It is also the place to bring up information that doesn't generally go in the CV/resume.

The cover letter is tailored to the position. It can be viewed as a combination abstract, introduction, and closing statement. Sometimes the requirements for the position are so detailed that the point you want to make gets lost in all the CV keywords you need to include.

The cover letter is the place to tell them why they should pay attention to that job 3 years ago. That job is the experience that makes you the best candidate for the position. It is OK to repeat some of the same information, but you should also expand on the information. Make it clear that this is the key part, and why it applies.